# Can I use the Lync Server 2010 SDK remotely?

Tags: lync

I'm looking at developing part of an intranet web site, and one of the requirements is to have a button that the user can click which will start a conversation in Lync with a contact they nominate.

The Client SDK would seem to be wonderful if I could access it from an external machine, but I can't see a way around this that will let me run C# code on a users machine (if anyone has any ideas feel free to suggest, but I know this sort of thing is guarded against).

So I'm now looking at the Server SDK, and the examples of it, and I can't work out if it's even possible to run the server SDK on a different machine from the server? I need to work out if this is even possible before trying to work out if I can meet the desired functionality with the Server SDK (which doesn't seem to be as nicely documented as that for the client sdk).

So my question is basically: can I access the features of the Lync Server 2010 SDK from a remote machine, and if so where do I look to get into doing that?

Any help here would be vastly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, no, it is not possible to access the server SDK remotely.

The only suitable workaround for this would be to create a web service on the server running Lync, exposing the necessary functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that Lync Server SDK be installed on the Lync server machine. Your development machine (with the SDK installed) does not even need to be on the same domain. 
Your custom application that you create using the SDK...I think that must be deployed in an application pool. I think the pool is often on an application server, which can be a separate computer.
The article and demo video here might shed some light:

[Lync Server 2013: Register a managed code application](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Lync-Server-2013-Register-a-managed-code-application)

[Register a managed application on Lync Server 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn600167.aspx)

Your scenario though - you say you want an "intranet web site, and one of the requirements is to have a button that the user can click which will start a conversation in Lync with a contact they nominate."

This sounds like a custom Lync client developed using Silverlight and the Lync client SDK. See the following video demo:

[Add Lync Controls to a Web Application](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Add-Lync-Controls-to-a-Web-Application)